# Save As method is creating runtime error for some users not others

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Run-time error '1004']I created a command button that auto saves the workbook into one of two file paths depending on info in the spreadsheet. This works fine for me but my colleague is gettting the follwing error everytime.

The method is extending the file path and adding \0BA1700 in this instance (this changes every time). This doesn't happen on my computer and the code works as it should. Here is the sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim pathUnder As String
Dim pathOver As String
Dim file As String

file = Range("D2").Value
pathUnder = "G:\Technical Services\LARGE CORPORATE UW\Full Insurance\FI Quote Spreadsheets (below 500)\"
pathOver = "G:\Technical Services\LARGE CORPORATE UW\Full Insurance\FI Quote Spreadsheets (above 500)\"

If Range("D4").Value = "" Or Range("D2").Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Save Failed. Please ensure there are values in both cells D2 and D4")
Else
If Range("D4").Value >= 500 Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=pathOver & file & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=pathUnder & file & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My colleague's computer didn't have the G drive mapped to the correct server so remapped it and now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some kind of exception? Are you sure nothing is currently using this file? Maybe you own program does?

Comment: not sure what you mean? The  workbook should be saved in the folder FI quote Speadsheets (above 500) or   FI quote Speadsheets (below 500). The error says the path doesnt exist which it doesnt, becuase somehow \0BA1700 (this changes each time) is being added to the file path so it is trying to save it in a folder which doesn't exist.